# ASP.NET Get correct listview item so I can delete it

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

```
protected void myOrdersListView_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "removeBtn")
            {             
                CabinTable.Rows.RemoveAt(Convert.ToInt32(e.Item.DataItemIndex));
                CabinAdapter.Update(CabinTable);
                Response.Redirect("Overview.aspx");
            }
        }
```

I have a database in Windows Azure and I want to delete a row after I click on a linkbutton in a listview. I have tried 100 different ways but I cant get it to work, please help me out!

How can I get the correct parameter in here? "CabinTable.Rows.RemoveAt(?)"

Comment: What do you mean by correct parameter? Is what you are passing causing the wrong row to be deleted?

Comment: Yeah. Ps2goat  just solved it for me tnx guys!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing a row from the collection, delete the row itself:

```
CabinTable.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.Item.DataItemIndex)].Delete();
```

The sample also calls `CabinTable.AcceptChanges();` after doing deletes, though I haven't tested to see if that is necessary in your case.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.delete(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Comment: I'm confused. How is this different than OP's attempt? [Per Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.removeat(v=vs.110).aspx): `Calling RemoveAt is the same as calling Delete and then calling AcceptChanges.`

Comment: The OP may not have needed to call `AcceptChanges`-- like I said, I didn't test.  However, the OP's case is different because a `DataAdapter` is being used.  The `DataAdapter` needs to know if a row has been deleted, and I'm assuming that this value is not properly set by calling `RemoveAt` on the `DataRowCollection`.

Comment: @ps2goat, thank you for the explanation. That makes sense. I see how the `DataAdapter` uses this now.